# Android / iOS Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) communication with multiple Services

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an iOS App advertising two BLE services (both **primary**) the following way:

```
peripheralManager.addService(containingService)
peripheralManager.addService(preciseService)
peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [containingService.UUID, preciseService.UUID]])
```

I verified with the LightBlue app that both services are advertised.

What I want to do on the Android side is to get a ScanResult for devices advertising the "*preciseService*". Filtering for it, the device is never found though. Not filtering at all, the device is found, but in the ScanRecord the method ***getServiceUUIDs*** only returns the UUID of "*containingService*".

I know that I can find all other Service UUIDs by connecting to it. In my app I do not want to connect to the device though. So my question is if someone knows why only one of the two advertised primary services is found in the ScanRecord?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should look at the raw bytes through [ScanRecord.getBytes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanRecord.html#getBytes()) so you can confirm whether they are both coming across at all, or if Android is just parsing the raw scan record incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that it was all about the length of two or more 128bit UUIDs being added. Adding one 128bit and one 32bit UUID worked fine.